# How does a Java class get input?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner to programming (and Java) and could use some help with the basic concepts.
This is a sample from my reading about constructors, set and get statements.

```
1   // Fig. 3.10: GradeBook.java
2   // GradeBook class with a constructor to initialize the course name.
3
4     public class GradeBook
5     {
6         private String courseName; // course name for this GradeBook
7
8         // constructor initializes courseName with String supplied as argument
9         public GradeBook( String name )
10        {
11              courseName = name; // initializes courseName
12        }
13
14        // method to set the course name
15        public void setCourseName( String name )
16        {  
17             courseName = name; // store the course name
18        } // end method setCourseName
19
20        // method to retrieve the course name
21        public String getCourseName()
22        {
23             return courseName;
24        } // end method getCourseName
25   
26        // display a welcome message to the GradeBook user
27        public void displayMessage()
28        {
29            // this statement calls getCourseName to get the
30            // name of the course this GradeBook represents
31            System.out.printf( "Welcome to the grade book for\n%s!\n",
32              getCourseName() );
33        }    // end method displayMessage
34
35    } // end class GradeBook
```

I am having a little difficulty understanding the steps going between sets and gets.  My book didn't really explain anything, but how do they prompt for the user to input data? Is the prompt for input part of one of these by default?  All I understand is that the method setCourseName( String name ) means the course name has to be a string.  But I don't understand the instance variable of courseName = name.  or the function of the getCourseName method.  Can you help me to understand this example?

Answer (score 1):

There's no user input in that example. It only writes some output in the displayMessage() method. You could use that class like this, for example:

```
public class GradeBookMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GradeBook gradeBook = new GradeBook("my course");
        gradeBook.displayMessage();
        gradeBook.setCourseName("some other course");
        gradeBook.displayMessage();
    }
}
```

Any prompting for input would have to be done by you. This class only gives you a way to hold some data: a course name, specifically. The constructor requires you to provide a name, which is stored in the `private String courseName;` field. The getter (getCourseName()) and setter (setCourseName()) return and modify the content of that field, respectively. The displayMessage() method just prints out a message to the console showing the current content of the field.

Answer (score 1):

`GradeBook` is a class and a specific gradebook would be an instance. Since each instance needs its own name (like each person has her own name), `courseName` is the variable to access that name. Hence `setCourseName( String name )` sets `courseName` to the value of the `name` parameter.

The `getCourseName()` method gives the name to anyone who calls it. Since `courseName` is private, you can't directly access it - and it is private in order to maintain encapsulation (you'll learn about this).

Getting input has nothing to do with that class. You basically make a call to the operating system (using other classes) and pass read string to whereever you want, e.g. the `setCourceName(...)` method of a `GradeBook` instance.

Edit: I'll try and give an example.

Imagine you have a sheet of paper with 3 boxes and 3 texts. The boxes represent a grade book whereas the texts are the names of 3 course names.

Since you don't know which book belongs to which course (the boxes are empty), you have to assign them by drawing a line from a text to the corresponding box. That's what `setCourseName(...)` would do.

Now you want to know which book/box belongs to which course. You follow the line from a box to a text and get the course name. That's what `getCourseName(...)` would do.

The line in that example would be the instance variable `courseName`.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The GradeBook class doesn't encapsulate any of the user input functionality.  Imagine that you might want to use this class in several different applications -- maybe a Web application (where the course name is entered in an HTML form), an Applet (a Java application embedded in a web page), or, as you seem to be referring to, a Console-based java application.  They would all get input from the user in different ways. Assuming a console-based application, a snippet of your main application code might look like this:

```
  System.out.print("Enter the course name: ");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  String courseName = br.readLine();
  GradeBook gb = new GradeBook(courseName);
  gb.displayMessage();
```

Note that since the only constructor for the GradeBook class requires a courseName, you would typically use setCourseName/getCourseName to modify the courseName on an existing GradeBook object, e.g. loaded from a data store.

Answer (score 1):

Think of Gradebook as an object, just like a physical gradebook. Like most objects, it performs no action itself: other forces act upon it.

A gradebook cannot prompt a user for input, or display output. Those things happen when outside forces act upon it.

In this case, a program can insert data into the gradebook like this:

```
gradebook->setCourseName( "History" );
```

When your program runs this statement, the course name ("History") is saved in the gradebook, in the property named 'courseName'.

Similarly, we can act on the gradebook to retrieve information from it.

```
gradebook->getCourseName();
```

When your program executes this statement, the gradebook will return the value we previously set for `courseName` ("History").

Some objects can perform complex actions, but this object is simple. As such, user input is not handled by the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

Those are just getters and setters for member variables of the class, meaning they define methods to get and set values of the variables. You won't actually get or set anything until you call those methods. In the constructor, there is an argument for courseName, meaning when you call Gradebook("Math"), the courseName variable is set to "Math".

Answer (score 0):

courseName is private so that nobody can change it. The getter and setter methods are there to allow and control the access to this private properties.

courseName = name 
assigns the var which the setter methode gets to the internal private one.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // This will initialize your class with value "java course" as your course 
    // name whenever the constructor is called. It acts like the default value 
    GradeBook GBobject1 = new GradeBook("java course");

    // System.in accepts the values from keyboard
    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter CourseName..!");

    // next() method returns a String. 
    // For other types, use nextInt(), nextDouble(), etc...
    String course= input.next();

    // Pass the course name as a parameter to your setCourseName(String) 
    // method in order to set the course name as you like.
    // This line sets the course name that you entered.
    GBobject1.setCourseName(course);

    // In order to display the name you have to call 
    // displayMessage() which in-turn calls setCourseName()
    // This will display the course name!
    GBobject1.displayMessage();
}
```

Write this main method in your GradeBook class or you can write in some other class.